# issue with material-ui select field

Tags: material-ui, formsy-material-ui

I've been trying to get started with material-ui.
It seems something's wrong with the SelectField. When opened, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiHA4.png).

Any advice?

Thanks!
Lior K

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what caused this,
This style came from normalize.css, which added {-webkit-appearance: button; } to the list items.
Once removed, issue was fixed.